# Cannot get my chromecast into developer mode

Tags: google-cast

I still cannot get my chromecast into developer mode.  I tried compiling the sample android app and my chromecast doesn't appear in the list of devices.  I have indeed checked "Send this Chromecast's serial number when checking for updates" and rebooted my device.  I even let it sit overnight to give it time to contact Google.  When i got to http://[my chromecast ip]:9222 I get connection refused.  I can ping it though.  And http://[my chromecast ip]:8008/apps/ returns an XML response.

When I first sent the request to Google, they said the whitelist was backlogged but shortly thereafter they said the backlog was cleared.

Any ideas besides the fact that maybe whitelisting didn't work on Google's backend?

Comment: Please post to the chromecast-updates mailing list to address your issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had same problem earlier

In earlier version of chrome-cast app (for android) there was an issue `Send this Chromecast's serial number when checking for updates` is uncheking always, So I removed that app and again installed new version. That bug was removed now. OPtion is by default Checked.

If it doesn't work then try to use other device. Surely that will solve your problem

Comment: When checking this box you have to click 'Done' at the end of the page before rebooting the Chromecast.

Comment: @svassr: Now no need of doing this.. Option is by default tick.